# How to add new field to user model in django serializers

Tags: python, django

Since i am very new to django, sorry for asking a very basic thing which i am not able to figure out.

I have a serializer like this

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print validated_data['user']
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data['user'])
        user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user

    def get_identifier(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(7))
```

i have fields like name,email,password,phoneNumber from view which gives me data like this if i print validated_data['user']

```
[(u'email', u'tes1@c.vom11'), (u'name', u'rohdaasais'), (u'password', u'rokl'), (u'phoneNumber', u'2323')])
```

Now i want add one more field in this user which identifier before saving 
so that it should come like this

```
[(u'email', u'tes1@c.vom11'), (u'name', u'rohdaasais'), (u'password', u'rokl'), (u'phoneNumber', u'2323'),(u'identifier', u'SJAJK77')])
```

but when i do this

```
validated_data['user']['identifier'] = self.get_identifier()
```

it didnt worked and says i am trying to access field which does not exists, how can i add this to user dict

EDITED:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password', 'picture', 'phoneNumber')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['identifier'] = self.get_identifier()
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        return user

    def get_identifier(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(7))
```

I have edited the question , and shown the UserSerializer also

Comment: is identifier  field in User model :?

Comment: yes , identifier is a field in user model

Comment: try depth = 1  just below this `fields = ('id', 'user')` or update the field in `UserSerializer()`

Comment: checked this, but not working,

Comment: and my user model have this field like this ,   identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=1,unique=True)

Comment: your should add identifier field name in Meta of UserSerializer

Comment: i have added this in fields of Meta , then it shows in django view so i made it readOnly=True , but after that it does not show up in validated_data , here is this ([(u'email', u'dds@sa.cp'), (u'name', u'ds'), (u'password', u'ds'), (u'phoneNumber', u'3232')])